# GTKmm on Windows (porting) - sigc::mem_fun returning errors from VC++ Express 2010 about deducing template arguments

Tags: windows, visual-c++, gtk, gtkmm, libsigc++

I am trying to port my GTKmm application developed in Linux into Windows. I have a treeview with multiple selections and I need to get those selections into an std::vector.  The code I use (and that works fine in Linux) is this:

```
        std::vector<Gtk::TreeModel::iterator> rows;
    mp_FileDetailsTree->treeSelection()->selected_foreach_iter(
        sigc::mem_fun(rows, &std::vector<Gtk::TreeModel::iterator>::push_back)
        );
```

On Windows, however, (Visual C++ Express 2010) I get a lot of this error (repeated quite a bit):

```
error C2784: 'sigc::bound_const_volatile_mem_functor7<T_return,T_obj,T_arg1,T_arg2,T_arg3,T_arg4,T_arg5,T_arg6,T_arg7> sigc::mem_fun(T_obj &,T_return (__thiscall T_obj2::* )(T_arg1,T_arg2,T_arg3,T_arg4,T_arg5,T_arg6,T_arg7) volatile const)' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' from 'overloaded function type'
      c:\devel\gtkmm\include\sigc++-2.0\sigc++\functors\mem_fun.h(6196) : see declaration of 'sigc::mem_fun'
```

Right at the sigc::mem_fun line.

Any idea how I can fix this? Googling has turned up nothing useful :(. I'm using GTKmm 2.22 (full Windows installer).

Comment: Nevermind, I have changed the code to not use sigc::mem_fun anymore but instead to use Gtk::TreeSelection::get_selected_rows() instead.

Answer (score 1):

Directly using std::vector::push_back as a signal handler is rather ambitious. I'm not surprised that the compiler is confused.

I would just use a regular signal handler method and call vector::push_back() inside that method.